# Prove $\inf_{x\in D} [f(x)g(x)]\le\sup_{x\in D}f(x)\cdot\inf_{x\in D} g(x).$

Tags: real-analysis

Can anyone give me some idea about the following problem? Many thanks!

Let $f,g:D\to\mathbb{R}$ be two bounded functions such that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are nonnegative for each $x\in D$. Show that 
$$\inf_{x\in D} f(x)g(x)\le\sup_{x\in D}f(x)\inf_{x\in D} g(x).$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** As $f(x) \leq \sup\limits_{x\in D}f(x)$, $f(x)g(x) \leq \left(\sup\limits_{x\in D}f(x)\right)g(x)$.

Comment: Ok, it works. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user65018: Are you the same user as Xiaoye Liao or are you two different users?